# Does burning a DVD/CD slower help assure it will not have errors?

Tags: dvd, speed, burning, compact-disc

If I have 16x speed DVDs and I burn them at 12x or 8x speed, does this help assure the data burnt to the disc will not have errors/flaws?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/664365/352186

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, yes. Faster a disk is burnt, higher is the chance the media may not have recorded it, and consequently higher is the chance of errors, especially with low/cheaper quality media.
More detailed explanation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314060928/http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/nov04/articles/qa1104-3.htm).

Answer (score 4):

The optical media has a lot of error correction.

Burning at fast speeds is said to introduce errors (there is a probability based on environment conditions).

However, most people at CDFreaks seem to suggest that is not really required.

I have usually done writes at full speed (matching the media limits) for data.

For, [audio](http://www.cdrfaq.org/faq03.html#S3-31) writes, I am a bit skeptical on the theories and slow down a little for safety.

Yet, have not confirmed burning faster would have been a problem yet.

I have a feeling that these audio speed reductions were useful in the earlier days when media, writers and specifically the audio-cd players were not quite up to mark with the optical media handling.

---

> [Specifying slower speeds is useful for correcting errors and buffer underruns](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cdburn.html). Newer drives with "burn-proof" technology (the opposite of what it's supposed to do; again, who comes up with these names?) are not plagued by buffer underruns as older drives are. [this is in 2003].