# CD/DVD burning speed depends on what?

Tags: dvd, speed, burning, compact-disc

Is there any dependency in writing speed based on the datatype.ie Different speeds for Music/Movie/Softwares with same data size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no dependency as such, but generally it is recommended that Audio CDs are burnt at slow ( ~4X ) speed since most audio CD players do not have error correction as sophisticated as data CD readers. In addition, as mentioned [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/19867/does-burning-a-dvd-cd-slower-help-assure-it-will-not-have-errors/19868#19868)

> Faster a disk is burnt, higher is the
>   chance the media may not have recorded
>   it, and consequently higher is the
>   chance of errors, especially with
>   low/cheaper quality media

Answer (score 2):

The only difference I have observed is in writing fragmented file(s) to the disc. If they're in order, it's going to run at ~full speed.

Other factors excluding the drive itself would be how much RAM you have, and the load on the system at the time :)

Answer (score 2):

the write speed may decrease if you're burning a huge number of small files 'on the fly'.

creating an ISO first and then burn the image to disc will guarantee a constant write spreed. some programs offer feature this by default (e.g. **[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)**, clear the box 'on the fly' and it will create an image prior to the burning process).

Comment: This used to be an issue, but I'd venture almost everyone has a PC fast enough these days to not require building an ISO in advance to keep speeds up.

Comment: i know, i'm only using it for Audio CDs, old habit.

Comment: and creating the ISO first is going to be a delay more than just accepting the "on the fly" recording, isn't it?

Comment: it does indeed. i'm only using this feature for the sake of accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any difference. All the burning software I know will burn the data at the maximum possible speed. There might be very slight differences due to the format when finalizing the cd, but normally not very noticeable. This means that it's the speed of the cd drive which is the determining factor.

Answer (score 1):

The burning speed depends on a few things:

1. How fast your PC/HDD is...if it can't read the files fast enough from your HDD, it wont be able to burn fast enough
2. Speed of your burner. Some 16x burners will actually be faster than other 16x burneres
3. The speed/type of the blank. Some brands of 16x blank discs will burn faster than others. Depends on what chemicals and so on they used. The burner reads some info hidden on the blank disc to see how fast to burn it.

One thing it should NOT depend on, is what type of data you are burning.